# Communicate with git server over two separated networks that have a remote desktop between them

Tags: git, remote-desktop

We have a network (network A) including several developer PC and a Git server. Some of our projects are located on PCs outside of our network (network B), which we communicate with them through remote desktop and develop that projects remotely, also build and run there.

In fact, we establish dual remote desktop connection. a remote desktop to a PC in our network (interface PC) and establish a second remote desktop through second LAN card of interface PC to connect to outside PC include projects. Because interface PC has two network cards, so project PC (outside PC) can't ping my Git server.

[image: our networks]

Now, my question is how can I connect my outside projects to the Git server and track development change in my Git server?

Comment: can you install a ssh-proxy on the interface server?

Comment: Using an RDP session through an RDP session is a strange set-up. What you need is a VPN or at least an SSH server with port forwarding. You should replace the RDP-interface-PC with an SSH server and stop misusing RDP for that.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes. interface PC has a Windows OS and the software installation access is open on it. But I did not understand what kind of topology you said. pls explain more.

Comment: @Robert The network B (Projects PC) is external and there is no way to change the configuration or its topology or type of access to it. So the only way to access interface PC to Projects PC given to us is RDP. But the interface PC is in our network and we can configure or change type of connection between developer PC and interface PC. Can you explain more about your solution?

Comment: I support the comment of @Robert: install a ssh server that supports *port forwarding* on the interface PC ([eg. putty](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html)). Configure it so that the project PC accesses the git repo as if it is available on the interface PC.

Comment: Thank you dear @TimothyTruckle. Would you please convert this comment to a whole solution as an answer in bellow this question?